# jitter when using jquery to alter background-position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here's the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzx0fcp5/1/)**.

It's the interface to cropping an image. As you can see the selection div takes the same background image and positions it to the negative of the top and left attributes of the selection div. In theory this should give a perfect overlap, but there's a jitter as you move the selection div around, and I can't seem to figure out what is causing it.

html

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="selection"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#main {
    width: 600px;
    height: 450px;
    position: relative;
    background: url("http://cdn-2.historyguy.com/celebrity_history/Scarlett_Johansson.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
}
#selection {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    background: url("http://cdn-2.historyguy.com/celebrity_history/Scarlett_Johansson.jpg");
    border: 1px dotted white;
    background-size: 600px 450px;
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var move = false;
    var offset = [];
    var selection = null;

    $("#selection").mousedown(function (e) {
        move = true;
        selection = $(this);

        offset = [e.pageX - selection.offset().left, e.pageY - selection.offset().top];
    });

    $("#selection").mousemove(function (e) {
        if (move == true) {
            selection.css("left", e.pageX - offset[0]);
            selection.css("top", e.pageY - offset[1]);

            selection.css("background-position", (((-selection.position().left) - 1) + "px " + ((-selection.position().top  ) - 1) + "px"));
        }
    });

    $("#selection").mouseup(function (e) {
        move = false;
    });

})
```

Comment: because this is not a zoom tool, why you need to replicate the background into the selection area? Can't you have a transparent selector?

Comment: There's going to be a cover layer that greys out the non selected area of the image. So I need to replicate the background in the selection area to achieve that effect.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that there is a value of `5` offset that needs to be added to ensure seamlessness

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/nzx0fcp5/2/

`offset = [e.pageX - selection.offset().left + 5, e.pageY - selection.offset().top + 5];`

Comment: It's still jittering I'm afraid. Can i ask why you think adding the offset would help?

Comment: That was the issue seemed to be when looking through the JS console. I must say that the jittering has disappeared when testing in my browser. MAC Chome

Answer (score 0):

So, while experimenting I discovered that this was only a problem at certain sizes of the image. At the original size it is no problem, neither at half nor a quarter of this size. It wasn't simply a matter of keeping the image in proportion not having the image square or using even pixel sizes. I'm assuming this had something to do with partial pixel sizes, but I'm not sure, and I couldn't see any way to work around this, at least none that seemed worth the effort.

So while checking out the code of other croppers I took a look at POF's image cropper, they seem to have got round the problem by not using the background-position property at all (I'm not sure if it's plugin or they coded it themselves). They just set the image down and then used a transparent selection div with 4 divs stuck to each edge for the shading. So there's no pixel crunching on the fly at all. I like the simplicity and lightweight nature of this design and knocked up a version myself in jsfiddle to see if I could get it to work well.

[new jitter free jsfiddle with no pixel crunching](http://jsfiddle.net/nzx0fcp5/9/)

I liked the solution for the preview box as well.

html

```
<body>
 <div id="main">
    <img src="http://flavorwire.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/scarlett_johansson.jpg" />
     <div id="upperShade" class="shade" > </div>
     <div id="leftShade" class="shade" > </div>
    <div id="selection"></div>
     <div id="rightShade" class="shade"></div>
     <div id="lowerShade" class="shade" ></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

css

```
#main {
   position:relative;
    width: 450px;
    height: 600px;
}
#selection {
    width: 148px;
    height: 148px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px dotted white;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.shade {
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;

}

#upperShade {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 600px;
}

#leftShade {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 150px;
    width: auto;
}

#rightShade {
    left: 150px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 450px;
}

#lowerShade {
    left:0px;
    top: 150px;
    width: 600px;
    height:  300px;
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var move = false;
    var offset = [];
    var selection = null;

    $("#selection").mousedown(function (e) {
        move = true;
        selection = $(this);

        offset = [e.pageX - selection.offset().left, e.pageY - selection.offset().top];
    });

    $("#selection").mousemove(function (e) {
        if (move == true) {
            selection.css("left", e.pageX - offset[0]);
            selection.css("top", e.pageY - offset[1]);
            setShade();
        }
    });

    function setShade() {
        $("#upperShade").css("height", selection.position().top);
        $("#lowerShade").css("height", 600 - (selection.position().top + 150));
        $("#lowerShade").css("top", selection.position().top + 150);
        $("#leftShade").css("top", selection.position().top);
        $("#leftShade").css("width", selection.position().left);
        $("#rightShade").css("top", selection.position().top);
        $("#rightShade").css("left", selection.position().left + 150);
        $("#rightShade").css("width", 450 - selection.position().left);
    }

    $("#selection").mouseup(function (e) {
        move = false;
    });

});
```